# How to merge two directorys in Clearcase?

Tags: unix, version-control, clearcase

- 1 directory has 2 files: `test1.c`, `test2.c`
- 2 directory has 0 files

How can I copy only `test1.c` to second directory, using "merge".

Answer (score 1):

First, the directory need to be the same, in two different branches (or you wouldn't talk of merging in this case, simply duplicating files)

Second, if you merge that directory between two version of said directory between two branches, you will end up with `test1.c` and `test2.c`... empty.
That is because merging a folder isn't enough: that only update the *list* of files, not the *content* of files within that folder.

The easiest way to recursively merge (the folder and everything inside) is to use the command [`cleartool findmerge`](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm) (for ClearCase 7.x, before ClearTeam 8.x).
See "[Clearcase: `findmerge` usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2730665/6309)".

A merge is **always performed in the destination view**, so go to a view which select the folder in the right destination branch (and where that folder is for now still empty):

```
cd /path/to/view/avob/yourFolder
cleartool findmerge . -nc -fver .../sourceBranch/LATEST -merge
```

Note: if you are [using ClearCase UCM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18733869/6309), you will have to [set an activity first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9764851/6309), before launching the merge.

Before completing the merge (ie before checking in everything), you will be able to remove (`cleartool rmname test2.c`) the file you don't want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But in this way I get two files in second branch. I need only one file.

Comment: @user3616393 you can remove it before merge completion. See my edited answer.

Comment: @VonC What do you mean by the .../sourceBranch/LATEST

Comment: @yanivx That syntax with the three dots means: '`.../subbranch`' whatever branches followed by `/subbranch`. You can see it used in http://stackoverflow.com/a/12140897/6309.

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick&dirty solution to merge 2 directorys in linux (bash)

merge.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# params
source="$1"
target="$2"

# prog
IFS="
"
if [[ ! -d $source ]]; then
  echo "sourcedir not exists!"
  exit 1
fi

[[ ! -d $target ]] && mkdir -p $target

cutlength=${#source}

for o in `find $source -type d`; do
  dir="${o:$cutlength}"
  newdir="$target$dir"
  [[ ! -d "$newdir" ]] && mkdir -p ${newdir}
done

for o in `find $source -type f`; do
  file="${o:$cutlength}"
  newfile="$target$file"
  [[ ! -f "$newfile" ]] && cp ${o} ${newfile}
done
```

I just wrote it to merge 2 directorys together, and it works fine for it. Its really dirty and hast almost none security code. So be carefull by copy&paste